# default timezone in mongdb using Date.now()

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I did this

```
const MySchema = new Schema({
  created_at: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now()
  }
})
```

but the data got inserted is 5 min early than my actual time in my laptop. I thought my laptop time is not accurate but I checked in google the result is the same with my laptop.

how does `Date.now()` in mongoose/mongodb? Is this a timezone issue?

Comment: The easiest is to pass timestamps true to your schema options: `var MySchema = new Schema({...}, { timestamps: true });` http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#timestamps

Comment: It is not related to mongodb or mongoose but related to javascript

Comment: @RatanUdayKumar are you sure?

Comment: @ippi that will handle for every property in the schema?

Comment: I'm not sure how I managed to misread this question so badly or not read at all it seems. Sorry!.  But 5 minutes is unlikely to be a timezone issue (which most of the time are about hours).